# How to change a sqlite table column value type from Django model?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I created a table before I code the Django app and now I merged both the app and the table with following command `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. However after some while I really need to change the value type of one of the column. Is it enough to chage it through the model file or do I need some additional steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a field in a Django model, Django itself doesn't know how to update your database accordingly (`syncdb` only add tables from new models).

You have two options:

- manually create your database tables;
- use a migration tool like [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that detects and generates migration files from changes made to your models;

I recommend the second option as it's programmatic, more error-proof and makes your life easier when you need to go back and forth between database schemas.

Comment: I will check this-out

Comment: Migrations have been included in Django for a long time.  Don't need an external package any longer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this. (in Django 2)

After making the necessary changes to the model.py file of your app, run command:

- `python manage.py makemigrations` - This will generate a new file in migration folder of your app.
- `python manage.py migrate` - This will apply those edits on actual databse.

To check if the changes have been applied, run command : `.schema <tablename>` in your terminal, after entering the sqlite command-line program.